# Scala: how to handle many params that can be None

Tags: scala, optional-parameters, scala-option

Right now I have many params that can be none, and I want to assign the whole expressiona default value.

Right now I'm doing things like

```
var name: Option[String] = None
var surname: Option[String] = Some("Smith")

val fullName:String = {
  name.map { name => 
    surname.map { surname => 
      surname + ", " + name
    }.getOrElse("unknown")
  }.getOrElse("unknown")
}
```

but it's a bit too verbose. I'd like to know what would be a more idiomatic and elegant way to handle it, ideally it would be something like (it's pseudo code, of course!):

```
val fullName = (name + ", " + surname).getOrElse("unknown")
```

or something similar...

(just avoiding the double .getOrElse would be great...)

Answer (score 15):

How about this

```
scala> val fullName = (for(n <-name;s <-surname) yield n + s).getOrElse("unknown")  
fullName: String = unknown
```

Comment: desugared: `surname flatMap (x => name map (x + ", " + _)) getOrElse "unknown"`

Answer (score 13):

You might want to learn a bit about *applicative functors*, as the same pattern can be used in all sorts of ways. Using scalaz, there is the applicative builder:

```
(name |@| surname)(_ + _)
```

What is going on is this:

```
(M[A] |@| M[B])(fabc) ~> M[C] //fabc is a function f: (A, B) => C
```

That is, the function `f` is being lifted into the realm of applicative functor `M`. This is particularly useful because it works with `Option`, `Validation`, `Promise`, `List`, `Stream` and many more. That is, just as you might use the expression:

```
(name |@| surname)(_ + _)
```

where `name` and `surname` are both `Option[String]`, you could switch them to be `ValidationNEL[Exception, String]` or `Promise[String]` and the code would still do the exact same thing (appropriate to the higher kind being used). This is very powerful.

Comment: @opensas here is even an 'Person' example: http://applicative-errors-scala.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/0.6/html/index.html HTH

Answer (score 2):

I've found this way:

```
val fullname = (name, surname) match {
  case (Some(x), Some(y)) => x + ", " + y
  case _ => "unknonw"
}
```

but it's still a bit verbose